# タイトル画面より遷移後、API通信を行わなくなる原因を突き止めたい。

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

#### 前提・実現したいこと

UnityにてAndroidの64bit版で正常に動作するものを出力したい。

#### 使用環境

- MacOS Mojave 10.14.6
- Unity 2018.1.6f1, 2018.1.9f2, 2018.2.21f1, 2018.3.14f1
- UTNotifications - Professional Local & Push Notification Plugin 1.8.2
- PlayMaker　1.9.0.p18
- Prime31 iOS and tvOS StoreKit In App Purchase Plugin 3.2
- iTween 2.0.10
- SpriteStudio 6 Player for Unity 1.1.19

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

最終結果はUnityにてAndroidの64bit出力を行いたいです。
「edit」→「project setting」→「player」にて「other settings」の
「Scripting Backend」で「il2cpp」を選択、「ARM64」にチェックをすれば64bitで出力できるところまでは、調べて把握しました。
そこで上記の通り設定し、ビルドを行ったところ
初期の状態でエラーが出たので、各アセットを最新のものでインポートしなおしたところ
ビルドはできる状態になりましたがタイトル画面から次の画面（ローディング画面）へ遷移したところで
まったくAPIへ通信を行わなくなる状態になりました。
Unityのバージョンを上述の通り2018.1.6f1→2018.1.9f2→2018.2.21f1→2018.3.14f1とUnityHUBを利用し上げていったのですが、
2018.1.9f2では2018.1.6f1と同様ビルドはできるのですが、通信を行わない状態
2018.2.21f1以降のバージョンでは、以下のエラーが出る状態です。
この問題を解決したく思っております。

```
Failed running /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2018.3.14f1/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/build/il2cppcore/il2cppcore.dll --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="Android" --architecture="ARM64" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="/Users/user/Documents/unityProject/***/workspace/vip/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Native/arm64-v8a/libil2cpp.so" --cachedirectory="/Users/user/Documents/unityProject/***/workspace/vip/Assets/../Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache" --additional-include-directories="/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2018.3.14f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/bdwgc/include" --additional-include-directories="/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2018.3.14f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/libil2cpp/include" --additional-libraries="/Users/user/Documents/unityProject/***/workspace/vip/Assets/Plugins/Prime31/libP31SharedTools.a" --tool-chain-path="/Users/user/Documents/android-ndk-r16b" --map-file-parser="/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2018.3.14f1/Unity.app/Contents/Tools/MapFileParser/MapFileParser" --generatedcppdir="/Users/user/Documents/unityProject/***/workspace/vip/Temp/StagingArea/Il2Cpp/il2cppOutput" --dotnetprofile="legacyunity" 

stdout:
Building libil2cpp.so with AndroidToolChain
    Output directory: /Users/user/Documents/unityProject/***/workspace/vip/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Native/arm64-v8a
    Cache directory: /Users/user/Documents/unityProject/***/workspace/vip/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache
ObjectFiles: 649 of which compiled: 649
    Time Compile: 43122 milliseconds Il2CppAttributes.cpp
    Time Compile: 24559 milliseconds Bulk_mscorlib_10.cpp
    Time Compile: 23801 milliseconds Il2CppTypeDefinitions.cpp
    Time Compile: 14850 milliseconds Il2CppInvokerTable.cpp
    Time Compile: 14498 milliseconds Bulk_Assembly-CSharp-firstpass_2.cpp
    Time Compile: 13819 milliseconds Il2CppMethodPointerTable.cpp
    Time Compile: 12101 milliseconds Bulk_Unity.TextMeshPro_1.cpp
    Time Compile: 11492 milliseconds Bulk_Unity.TextMeshPro_2.cpp
    Time Compile: 10931 milliseconds Il2CppMetadataUsage.cpp
    Time Compile: 9849 milliseconds Bulk_Generics_15.cpp
Total compilation time: 151215 milliseconds.
il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: /Users/user/Documents/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ @"/var/folders/f7/dsvfx8nd0nn2mxk6hh8vs1tc0000gn/T/tmpEvMoxV.tmp" -o "/Users/user/Documents/unityProject/***/workspace/vip/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/linkresult_3883156B0E1C225D689513AA4C83DDBF/libil2cpp.so" -shared -Wl,-soname,libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--build-id --sysroot "/Users/user/Documents/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64" -gcc-toolchain "/Users/user/Documents/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64" -target aarch64-none-linux-android -Wl,--wrap,sigaction -L "/Users/user/Documents/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/arm64-v8a" -lgnustl_static -llog -rdynamic -fuse-ld=bfd "/Users/user/Documents/unityProject/***/workspace/vip/Assets/Plugins/Prime31/libP31SharedTools.a"

/Users/user/Documents/unityProject/***/workspace/vip/Assets/Plugins/Prime31/libP31SharedTools.a: file not recognized: File format not recognized
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.PostprocessObjectFiles(HashSet`1 objectFiles, CppToolChainContext toolChainContext)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)
stderr:

Unhandled Exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: /Users/user/Documents/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ @"/var/folders/f7/dsvfx8nd0nn2mxk6hh8vs1tc0000gn/T/tmpEvMoxV.tmp" -o "/Users/user/Documents/unityProject/***/workspace/vip/Library/il2cpp_android_arm64-v8a/il2cpp_cache/linkresult_3883156B0E1C225D689513AA4C83DDBF/libil2cpp.so" -shared -Wl,-soname,libil2cpp.so -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--build-id --sysroot "/Users/user/Documents/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64" -gcc-toolchain "/Users/user/Documents/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64" -target aarch64-none-linux-android -Wl,--wrap,sigaction -L "/Users/user/Documents/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/arm64-v8a" -lgnustl_static -llog -rdynamic -fuse-ld=bfd "/Users/user/Documents/unityProject/***/workspace/vip/Assets/Plugins/Prime31/libP31SharedTools.a"

/Users/user/Documents/unityProject/***/workspace/vip/Assets/Plugins/Prime31/libP31SharedTools.a: file not recognized: File format not recognized
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.PostprocessObjectFiles(HashSet`1 objectFiles, CppToolChainContext toolChainContext)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)
   at Program.Main(String[] args)

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunProgram(Program, String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:128)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunNetCoreProgram(String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase, Action`1) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:79)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:RunIl2CppWithArguments(List`1, Action`1, String) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:366)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:RunCompileAndLink() (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:247)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils:RunCompileAndLink(String, String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action`1, RuntimeClassRegistry) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:49)
UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayer(String[], String, BuildTarget, BuildOptions)
AppBuild:RunBuild(PreSettngs, BuildTarget, BuildOptions) (at Assets/Classes/Unique/Editor/AppBuild.cs:75)
AppBuild:BuildAndroidDebugPlayer() (at Assets/Classes/Unique/Editor/AppBuild.cs:30)
```

#### 試したこと

UnityHubでバージョンを一つずつ上げ、ビルドを試してみました。

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/206885

Answer (score 0):

SQLite4Unity3dが古く64Bit対応ではありませんでした。